# Missing only one bar in bar-chart

Tags: ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm working on a duplicate bar chart using ggplot and I'm almost getting what I want, except for this error I couldn't fix.

The data I'm plotting:

```
      comp     reg counts
1   C0xC12      up    569
2   C0xC12    down    845
3   C0xC24      up    420
4   C0xC24    down    227
5   C0xT12      up   2904
6   C0xT12    down   2989
7   C0xT24      up   2536
8   C0xT24    down   2309
9  C12xC24      up    314
10 C12xC24    down    138
11 C12xT12      up   3006
12 C12xT12    down   3082
13 C12xT24      up   2795
14 C12xT24    down   2577
15 C24xT12      up   1381
16 C24xT12    down   1901
17 C24xT24      up    482
18 C24xT24    down    862
19 T12xT24      up   1732
20 T12xT24    down   1464
21  C0xC12   uppcw      7
22  C0xC12 downpcw     15
23  C0xC24   uppcw     10
24  C0xC24 downpcw      4
25  C0xT12   uppcw     56
26  C0xT12 downpcw     58
27  C0xT24   uppcw     49
28  C0xT24 downpcw     41
29 C12xC24   uppcw      8
30 C12xC24 downpcw      2
31 C12xT12   uppcw     64
32 C12xT12 downpcw     50
33 C12xT24   uppcw     48
34 C12xT24 downpcw     39
35 C24xT12   uppcw     35
36 C24xT12 downpcw     40
37 C24xT24   uppcw     11
38 C24xT24 downpcw     15
39 T12xT24   uppcw     33
40 T12xT24 downpcw     30
```

The code I'm running:

```
teste <- read.table("teste.txt", sep = "\t", header = TRUE)
ggplot(data = teste, 
       mapping = aes(x = comp, fill = reg,
                     y = ifelse(test = reg == "down" | reg == "downpcw", 
                                yes = -counts, no = counts))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = abs, limits = max(teste$counts) * c(-1,1)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=counts), vjust=0.5, color="black", size=3.0, nudge_y = c(-130,130))+
  labs(y = "DEGs", x = "Groups comparisons") + scale_fill_manual(values=c("#98FB98","#FA8072","#00FF00","#FF0000")) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("T12xT24", "C24xT24", "C24xT12", "C12xT24", "C12xT12", "C12xC24", "C0xT24", "C0xT12", "C0xC24","C0xC12")) +
  coord_flip()
```

That's the plot I'm getting

[image]
notice that "C12xT12" biggest bar is not showing, just its size (3082).

I've looked for solutions but found nothing and I can't come up with one alone, so I'm asking if anyone has ever dealt with this issue before.

Comment: Welcome to SO. +1 for adding a reprex and clear question. Next time consider making a smaller data frame and using `dput(your sample data frame)`, which makes this easier to read for us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from your `scale_y_continuous`.
You're setting it to the max of the `counts` column which cuts off the max column as it's exactly at the limit of the plot.
If you multiply the max with 1.05 instead of 1, everything should work.
Change the corresponding part of the `scale_y_continuous` to: `limits = max(teste$counts) * c(-1.05,1.05)`.

Also some best practice colour advice: avoid using red-green combination as ~10% of men are colourblind and cannot tell shades of these colours apart.

Comment: Got it, thank you! I appreciate your advice as well, although in this case I must use these colors as they are standard to represent up- and down- gene expression.

Comment: yeah, i know - i also work in biology. however, we're currently moving away from red/green to magenta/green, b/c it's colourblind friendly.

Comment: Cool, haven't heard about it. Then I'll update my plot.

Comment: there are also other options. check out Fig. 4 [here](https://dmm.biologists.org/content/8/3/311).

Answer (score 2):

The line `scale_y_continuous(labels = abs, limits = max(teste$counts) * c(-1,1)) +`
 is "guilty" here, because it limits the axis to exactly 3082. This causes ggplot to clip the bar.
Either leave out the `limits = max(teste$counts) * c(-1,1)` or use something like `scale_y_continuous(labels = abs, limits = max(teste$counts) * c(-1.02,1.02)) +`

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, your code is full of redundance. If you accept an answer, consider accepting the previous answers because they got to the point of the problem. I just add this one to make suggestions to improve the code.
It's not only a matter of style, also of clarity and can reduce problems - In general, ggplot makes a lot automatically for you. E.g., in your plot, there is really no need to manually set the `scale_discrete` breaks and to manually set the `scale_continuous` limits.

Other comments to the code are in the code block - have a look. Although 10% color blindness might be mildly exaggerated, this is indeed a concern. Have a look at [this fabulous website](http://colorbrewer2.org) - it will help you to chose nice colors.

```r
library(ggplot2)
teste <- data.table::fread("      comp     reg counts
1   C0xC12      up    569
                  2   C0xC12    down    845
                  3   C0xC24      up    420
                  4   C0xC24    down    227
                  5   C0xT12      up   2904
                  6   C0xT12    down   2989
                  7   C0xT24      up   2536
                  8   C0xT24    down   2309
                  9  C12xC24      up    314
                  10 C12xC24    down    138
                  11 C12xT12      up   3006
                  12 C12xT12    down   3082
                  13 C12xT24      up   2795
                  14 C12xT24    down   2577
                  15 C24xT12      up   1381
                  16 C24xT12    down   1901
                  17 C24xT24      up    482
                  18 C24xT24    down    862
                  19 T12xT24      up   1732
                  20 T12xT24    down   1464
                  21  C0xC12   uppcw      7
                  22  C0xC12 downpcw     15
                  23  C0xC24   uppcw     10
                  24  C0xC24 downpcw      4
                  25  C0xT12   uppcw     56
                  26  C0xT12 downpcw     58
                  27  C0xT24   uppcw     49
                  28  C0xT24 downpcw     41
                  29 C12xC24   uppcw      8
                  30 C12xC24 downpcw      2
                  31 C12xT12   uppcw     64
                  32 C12xT12 downpcw     50
                  33 C12xT24   uppcw     48
                  34 C12xT24 downpcw     39
                  35 C24xT12   uppcw     35
                  36 C24xT12 downpcw     40
                  37 C24xT24   uppcw     11
                  38 C24xT24 downpcw     15
                  39 T12xT24   uppcw     33
                  40 T12xT24 downpcw     30")
```

Now the plot

```
ggplot(data = teste, aes(x = comp, y = ifelse(grepl('down', reg), -counts, counts), fill = reg)) + 
    ## I reduced your statement to a simple "grepl" statement, and you don't really need to name your ifelse arguments
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label=counts), vjust=0.5, size=3.0, nudge_x = c(-0.1,0.1)) +
    ### I think nudge_x is what you want - your labels were overlapping
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'RdBu') + ## that's one of the palettes from colorbrewer
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-08-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your considerations. I am a beginner at programming in R and I can read the codes but I'm stil not able to write one by myself, so usually I look for what I want and add by pieces. I know that's not how one should do it but I'm still learning and sometimes I just need it finished. Anyway, setting `scale_x_discrete` was the way I found to set the order I want, with "C0xC12" at the top. And yes, `nudge.x` is a thing I was looking for, thanks! One thing I don't understand is: by setting `grepl('down', reg)` in ifelse argument, does it also take 'downpcw' together?

Comment: That's what I though! that's why I made those suggestions. `grepl(xxx)` looks for a string or, more general, for a 'regex' (regular expression), i.e. is will capture all 'down's in your variable `reg`. Fair point with the order of x - that's always a bit trick and sometimes painful. It can be helpful to use factors and order the levels instead, but factors may be very confusing at the start. One more thing - it would be nice for one of the others if you could accept their answer - this gives rep points. More importantly, the answer won't be marked 'unanswered' any more.

Comment: Awsome. Thank you so much.